# Can I install Safari Queue on PocketBook Touch HD?

Tags: android

I'm thinking about getting an ebook reader (sometimes I read on my smartphone, but I want a paper-like screen), and I'm thinking about the PocketBook Touch HD. However I want to be able to read books from safaribooksonline.com.

I have the impression that on most ebook readers you can't install apps from Google Play. I could read safari books with the web browser, but when the ebook reader runs Android and there's an app that's really better than the browser, it seems really silly to use the browser.

I've also read some discussions about people who had a problem with the software of their ebook reader and installed CoolReader instead. How come? Ebook readers do allow installing Android apps after all? This is very confusing.

Comment: Any update on this? I found that Onyx Boox Nova runs Android and has an option to enable Google Playstore Another option is this tool to create an epub file https://github.com/lorenzodifuccia/safaribooks But it would be better if it was possible to use the safari app on the pocketbook